# Accessing WinMo6 GPS through Pocket IE

Tags: windows-mobile, gps, pocket-ie

Does anyone know if it is possible to access the GPS on a Windows Mobile device through Pocked Internet Explorer, similar to how you do it on a blackberry and iphone (javascript)? If so, how do you do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Possible" is broad.  Yes, it's possible, but it's not simple.  You have to create an Active X component (that implements IObjectSafety so it's browser compatible) and have the page use that control to access the GPS driver.